# HTML5 Video readyState with Event Listener

Tags: javascript, html5-video, readystate

Trying to display a 'loading' div until my MP4 is done buffering. Seems like it should do the trick, but no go- loading stays up even when done buffering! Any suggestions?

```
<video id="homeVideo" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;" autoplay>
<source src="/media/micro_home.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<style>#slider_loading {display: visible;}
<div id="slider_loading" class="slider_loading"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var video = document.getElementById("homeVideo");

if (video.readyState === 4) {
    document.getElementById('homeVideo')style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `poster` attribute to work this out, see the example:

```
<video controls poster="/images/w3html5.gif">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

> "The poster attribute specifies an image to be shown while the video is
>   downloading, or until the user hits the play button. If this is not
>   included, the first frame of the video will be used instead."
>
> See more at the [poster attribute docs](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_poster.asp).